# Google Cloud Speech API protobuf is causing 'debugAndroidTestCompile' not found

Tags: android, google-speech-api

I have copied and compiled the source code for speech api last month on this location https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech 
and works. Now, when I revisited it, I'm having a ***Configuration with name 'debugAndroidTestCompile' not found.*** error.

What is causing this? If you ask me how did I know it is the one, I did the process of elimination. I removed one by one on the gradle file and sync. When I removed ***apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'*** the error disappears.

Answer (score 14):

Update the `protobuf` version to the latest in `build.gradle`. Currently it's `0.8.8`, check the latest version from the GitHub repository [*Protobuf Plugin for Gradle*](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#latest-version).

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.8'
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note you will find this in project level build.gradle file.